# Missing tables in AdevntureWorksDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Recently I found some old questions that involve querying data from AdevntureWorksDB across several operations(DML,DDL).

One such question was :

**Create and execute a query that computes the total number of employees with the
Addressline2 value as NULL**

Now the query for this, is very simple as it appears but the challenge for me was to find tables whom I could join and retrieve data.

Employee details were in Employee table and Address details were in Address table.
And no keys to join both these tables.

Now ,since I can be sure that these questions were created many years ago, my question here is whether there existed a table called EmployeeAddress that served the purpose of a join table between the base tables Employee and Address.

I started out with SQL hardly 3 years back. So any of you experienced people here, can you please help me on this.

I did a bit of research and found the following:

Microsoft website labels this as a conceptual table that's deprecated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms124671%28v%3dsql.100%29

Saw the same table on another website too.

http://www.sqledit.com/sr/samples/frames2/adventureworks.html

I recently downloaded the oldest available backup file for SQL server ,i.e. 2008R2,but still fail to see this table.

Do I need to change any compatibility settings in SSMS to view this table in 2008R2?

Also, if someone can tell me a source for the version of AdventureWorks that has this table, I would be really glad.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `HumanResources.vEmployee` view, which joins several related tables, including `Person.Address`, to return employee detail information.

Comment: I am aware of the view vEmployee.But as you can see in the links shared, we did have a table by EmployeeAddress name.

Comment: You don't need `HumanResource.EmployeeAddrress` table for the query exercise in your question. Use the view directly (e.g. `SELECT * FROM HumanResources.vEmployee WHERE AddressLine2 IS NULL;`) or better yet, learn to write the query using from the underlying tables.